# Play random audio file on click JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I am using the following code to play a random audio file (files named from 1.wav to 15.wav) The variable 'file' is displaying random files. But on each mouse click they are playing the same file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").click(function() {

        function explode() {
            var file = Math.floor(Math.random() * 14) + 1 + '.wav';
            var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
            audioElement.setAttribute('src', file);
            audioElement.setAttribute('autoplay', 'autoplay');
            //audioElement.load()

            $.get();
            audioElement.addEventListener("load", function() {
                audioElement.play();
            }, true);
        }
        setTimeout(explode, 5000);
    });
});
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/px8gm42p/

Comment: @RayonDabre thanks. That one worked!